# SELECT Query working in managment studio but not working in VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I've a problem in a Excel/VBA: getting data in a recordset from Microsoft SQL Server I receive "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors..." The error occurs when I open my recordset.

The query is a SELECT query without errors (launched in Management Studio) but it gives me error using a recordset in VBA.

Weird thing: the query is SELECT SUM... and if I remove SUM I don't get the error.

Could you help me please?

Code:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Set W1 = ActiveWorkbook

sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SERVERNAME;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=DBNAME;" & _
    "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
conn.Open sConnString

conn.CommandTimeout = 30  

t_sql = ""
t_sql = t_sql & "SELECT" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "SUM(rroc.PrezzoUnit / (Cambi.VALORE * (1 + ISNULL(nis.Aliquota, ni.Aliquota)))) AS ordinato" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "FROM RepOrdiniClienti roc WITH (NOLOCK)" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "inner join RepRigheOrdiniClienti rroc WITH (NOLOCK) ON rroc.RepOrdiniClienti_ID = ID_RepOrdiniClienti" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "inner join repclientidestinatari rcd WITH (NOLOCK) ON repclientidestinatari_id = id_repclientidestinatari" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "inner join NAZIONI WITH (NOLOCK) ON nazioni_id = id_nazioni" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "INNER JOIN CountryBP WITH (NOLOCK) ON CountryBP_ID = ID_CountryBP" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "INNER JOIN Valuta WITH (NOLOCK) ON Valuta_ID = ID_VALUTA" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "left join Articolo Articolo WITH (NOLOCK) ON rroc.codice10 = Articolo.Codice10" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "left join Stagioni Stagioni WITH (NOLOCK) ON Articolo.Stagione_di_Vendita_ID = ID_Stagioni" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "INNER JOIN Cambi WITH (NOLOCK) ON Cambi.Valuta_ID=roc.Valuta_ID AND CONVERT(DATE,roc.Data,103) = CONVERT(DATE,Cambi.DATA,103)" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "left join Nazioni_intrastat ni WITH (NOLOCK) ON ni.Nazioni_ID = rcd.Nazioni_ID and roc.Data between ni.DataInizio and ni.DataFine" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "inner join commitenti c WITH (NOLOCK) ON rcd.Commitenti_ID=c.ID_Commitenti" & vbCrLf
t_sql = t_sql & "left join nazioni_intrastat_societa nis WITH (NOLOCK) ON nis.societa_id=c.Societa_id and nis.nazioni_id=rcd.nazioni_id and (roc.Data between nis.DataInizio and nis.DataFine)" & vbCrLf

ordinato = 0         
rs.Open stringa_sql, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    If Not (IsNull(rs("ordinato"))) Then ordinato = ordinato + CDbl(rs("ordinato"))
End If
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

Comment: Yes I need only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing adOpenDynamic to adOpenStatic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for tip! It's working now.. 
What do you think about the error coming only with SELECT SUM but not with SELECT?

Comment: I didn't think that you can put a dynamic cursor on an aggregate because it is not possible to update an aggregate. Take SUM away and it is no longer an aggregating query because there is no GROUP BY.